# search with filter by token count

Tags: elasticsearch, token

Fields in documents are analyzed, to create token.

1. `{"message":"hello world"}` -> token: ["hello", "world"]
2. `{"message":"hello"}` -> token: ["hello"]
3. `{"message":"world"}` -> token: ["world"]
4. `{"message":"hello java"}` -> token: ["hello", "java"]
5. `{"message":"java"}` -> token: ["java"]

Is there a possibility to search all documents in which a specific field contains a given token and 1 or more token other token?

- Result for the given example for token "hello" would be:

  - 1,4
- For "world":

  - 1

As described in [termvectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html), one can access the tokens or statistics about them. This only works for specific documents but not as search filter for a query or aggregation.
Would be nice if someone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`token_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#token_count) type for this. For instance, in your mapping, you can define `message` as a multi-field to contain the message itself (i.e. "hello", "hello world", etc) and also the number of tokens of the message. Then you'll be able to include constraints on the word count in your queries.

So your mapping for `message` should look like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/tests -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "string",           <--- message is a normal analyzed string
          "fields": {
            "word_count": {           <--- a sub-field to include the word count
              "type": "token_count",
              "store": "yes",
              "analyzer": "standard"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you can query for all documents having `hello` in the message, but only those whose `message` has more than one token. With the following query, you'll only get `hello java` and `hello world`, but not `hello`

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/tests/test/_search -d '
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "hello"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "message.word_count": {
              "gt": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Similarly, if you replace `hello` with `world` in the above query, you'll only get `hello world`.